# Does variable order matter for sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I am facing a weird issue with sscanf, I can read all values properly when I pass arguments in a particular order and it is working if I change the order. Could someone explain why is this weird behavior ?

### Non-Working case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t oct1, oct2, oct3, oct4;

    char buf[20];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    sprintf(buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    int f = sscanf(buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d", &oct1, &oct2, &oct3, &oct4);
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d \nSuccessfully read - %d\n", oct1, oct2, oct3, oct4, f);
    return 0;
}

Output:
    1.2.3.4
    0.0.0.4
    Successfully read - 4
```

### Working case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t oct1, oct2, oct3, oct4;

    char buf[20];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    sprintf(buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    int f = sscanf(buf,"%d.%d.%d.%d", &oct4, &oct3, &oct2, &oct1);
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d \nSuccessfully read - %d\n", oct1, oct2, oct3, oct4, f);
    return 0;
}
Output:
    1.2.3.4  
    4.3.2.1
    Successfully read - 4
```

Comment: Hi Sorry I figured out the issue, i declaring the variable as uint8_t and using "%d" formatter to read the value hence it is behaving weird, once i change the variable to uint32_t it works fine, BTW what is the formatter for uint8_t ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct format specifier for `uint8_t` is `SCNu8` macro from `<inttypes.h>`. The usage should be:

```
sscanf(buf,"%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8 ".%" SCNu8, &oct1, &oct2, 
                                                       &oct3, &oct4);
```

Similarly, `SCNu32` and `SCNu16` for `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` respectively and `SCNd8`, `SCNd16`, `SCNd32` for `int8_t`, `int16_t` and `int32_t` respectively.

Note that these fixed with integer types (introduced in C99) are optional types.

Aside:

`sprint` is dangerous since they can't prevent buffer overflow. Suggest using `snprintf()` instead:

```
snprintf(buf,sizeof buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Also, `memset()`ing `buf` is needless since you are going to write into it immediately (Note that `snprintf()` always NUL terminates the buffer).

Comment: Don't you mean `SCNu8` instead of `SCNd8`?  Anyway it's "%hhu" if you prefer that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about SCNu8 ? I tried the below one and it didnt work
 **Int f = sscanf(buf,"%SCNu8.%SCNu8.%SCNu8.% SCNu8", &oct1, &oct2,                                                              &oct3, &oct4);**

why isnt SCNu8  given inside the quotes

Comment: @kris_lazybum Notice the difference in usage between yours and in the answer. You can't have them inside double quotes. They are marcos. So they won't expand if you quote them.

Comment: Detail: "snprintf() always NUL terminates the buffer" when the size passed > 0 - which of course `sizeof buf > 0`.  This useful feature allows calculating the size needed without providing a right-sized buffer.

Answer (score 4):

In C, type `int` can save at least integers in -32767～32767, and it won't fit in 8-bit.

In the other hand, `uint8_t` is granteed to have exactly 8 bits.

For that reason, passing `uint8_t*` to where `int*` is required for `%d` format of `sscanf()` will cause type mismatch and this is *undefined behavior*.

Both of the programs have the same issue, so the "Working case" worked just by chance.

I guess it "worked" because the machine is little endian and `oct3` had higher address than `oct4`, so the value of `oct3` wasn't destroyed in reading of `oct4`, and the same thing can be said for `oct2` and `oct1`.
On the other hand, if you read `oct3` before reading `oct4` in this condition, the value of `oct3` may be destroyed as the part of data for  `oct4`.

Comment: it works not only because of  little endian but also because that architecture (probably x86) allows non-aligned access. Otherwise a segfault would occur

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of the variables you use. `scanf` expects an `int*` for `%d` arguments, and you use `uint8_t*`. Thus, when `scanf` writes over the variables, it overruns the memory address and in your non working case it overwrites the other variables. This happens because they follow one another in terms of memory layout.

It only happens in one of the cases since it depends which variable is written to first (effectively overwriting previous writes).

To solve this, simply use `int`s as required.